# I have trouble finding all the 3-digit numbers whose sum of digits equal my target number

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Input
The input consists of exactly 3 lines
(x - interval start (inclusive))
(y - interval end (inclusive))
(t - target sum)

(example Input) =
'300',
'400',
'4'
(What it should Output) =
'301',
'310',
'400'

```
let input = [
    '300',
    '400',
    '4'
  
];
 
let print = this.print || console.log;
let gets = this.gets || ((arr, index) => () => arr[index++])(input, 0);
 

var  remainder, sumOfDigits = 0;




 var n1 = +gets();
 var n2 = +gets();
 var n3 = +gets();

 for (i=n1;i<=n2;i++){
    while(i)
    {
        remainder = i % 10;
        sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits + remainder;
        i = Math.floor(n/10);
        if(sumOfDigits=n3){
            print(i);
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: You're changing your `for` loop counter in your `while` loop...

Comment: How am I able to combine the two of them?

Comment: copy the value of i into a different variable and use it

Comment: Perhaps `n=i; while (n) { ...` note you would also need to change `remainder = i % 10` to `remainder = n % 10` and `i = Math.floor(n/10)` to `n = Math.floor(n/10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues in the code you provided, such as using "n" instead of "i" in the loop and using an assignment "=" instead of a comparison "==" in the if statement.

```js
let input = ['300','400','4'];

let gets = this.gets || ((arr, index) => () => arr[index++])(input, 0);

let n1 = +gets();
let n2 = +gets();
let n3 = +gets();

for (let i = n1; i <= n2; i++) {
    let remainder, sumOfDigits = 0;
    let num = i;
    while (num) {
        remainder = num % 10;
        sumOfDigits += remainder;
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    }
    if (sumOfDigits === n3) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to you.